# Error: Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject?' to a value of type 'NSURL'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Geting error : **Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject?' to a value of type 'NSURL'**

My code:

```
var videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
    var mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
    var videoURL = NSURL()



 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){

              // error in below first line

        self.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]
      mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
        self.videoPlayer.contentURL = videoURL
        self.videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,460)
        self.view.addSubview(self.videoPlayer.view)
        self.videoPlayer.play()

         }
```

How to change that code to resolve my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]` is of type `AnyObject?` but `self.videoURL` is of type `NSURL`.

Safely cast the result as NSURL:

```
if let vURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
    self.videoURL = vURL
}
```

Here's your code fixed:

```
var videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
var mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
var videoURL = NSURL()

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let vURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
        self.videoURL = vURL
    } else {
        print("oops, no url")
    }
    mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
    self.videoPlayer.contentURL = videoURL
    self.videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,460)
    self.view.addSubview(self.videoPlayer.view)
    self.videoPlayer.play()

}
```

Comment: please see my edited post. does it correct. if so i am getting error. please i am new to ios .please help me out